# How to open and close DVD-RW with C++?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to apologize for bad English.
In my system, the CD drive is occupied by another device and the program code does not work correctly, what should I use to open and close the DVD-RW drive?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MCI_OPEN_PARMS OpenParm;
    MCI_SET_PARMS SetParm;
    MCIDEVICEID dID;
    OpenParm.lpstrDeviceType=L"CDAudio";
    mciSendCommand(0, MCI_OPEN, MCI_OPEN_TYPE, (DWORD_PTR)&OpenParm);
    dID = OpenParm.wDeviceID;
    mciSendCommand(dID, MCI_SET, MCI_SET_DOOR_OPEN, (DWORD_PTR)&SetParm);
    Sleep(3000);
    mciSendCommand(dID, MCI_SET, MCI_SET_DOOR_CLOSED, (DWORD_PTR)&SetParm);
    mciSendCommand(dID, MCI_CLOSE, MCI_NOTIFY, (DWORD_PTR)&SetParm);
    return 0;
}
```

[My System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uTBE.png)

What use instead CDAudio?

Comment: I found [this code](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/cd-rom/article.php/c5775/CDREXE--OpenClose-CD-Drives-Programmatically.htm)